Why android app is built with different version code and name than what is specified in Gradle file when debuggable is set to false?
enter image description hereI'm trying to publish my android app to Google play store. It seems to me that I have to set debuggable to false (in gradle file). But, the issue what that is, when I set it to false and I built the app, it gets built (.aab) or just regular build with different version code and name than what I specified in gradle file!!!! The version code increases every time I commit to the branch and the version name includes my commit name!!
If I set debuggable to true, when building the app, it does get built with version code and name of whatever I specify in gradle file.
My question is, how do I make the app when it is built to pickup the version code and name from gradle file when debuggable is set to false?
I tried to set debuggable to true and publish app to google (since setting it to true makes the build to pickup the version code and name that I specify in gradle), but I get an error in google saying app was not signed.
enter image description here

The two images you have added are identical, shouldn't they show a difference? Anyway normally you simply change the build type from debug to release instead if manually changing the debuggable flag.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I finally found the answer, seems like gradle updated how to set version code and name. So, you need to set it as follow and this worked for me:
android {
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField("int", "VERSION_CODE", "your version code")
    buildConfigField("String","VERSION_NAME", "\"your version name)}\"")
}

buildTypes {
             -------
            }

}

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
